# How to get percentage result from two table in SQL and show it with php?

Tags: php, sql

Helo friends, I am new in SQL and PHP code, so I need your help.

This is my SQL table with fields (`id`,`product_name`, `id_category`, `id_store`, `regular_price`,`sale_price`,`percentage`).  Can someone help me to get value for this field "percentage. I need to use this formula :

```
  (($regular_price-$sale_price)/$sale_price)*100;
```

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf168.png)

After I get this "percentage" value, I need to show all table fields.
In this example I was use INNER JOIN to show name of the value from other 2 tables (product category and store).

```
<?php
   if(!require_once('conn.php'))
   {
       die("Error");
   }

   $upit = "SELECT * FROM artikal INNER JOIN category ON id_category = category.id
                                    INNER JOIN store ON id_store = store.id
        " ;
   $rezultat = $conn->query($upit);    
?>
                   <?php while($red = $rezultat->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                   <tr>
                       <td><?= $red['product_name']; ?></td>
                       <td><?= $red['id_category']; ?></td>
                       <td><?= $red['id_store']; ?></td>
                       <td><?= $red['regular_price']; ?>$</td>
                       <td><?= $red['sale_price']; ?>$</td>
                       <td>**percentage discount I need here**</td>
                   </tr>
               <?php } ?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: As you can see the code to display the database fields, what code have you tried to display the calculated number that you need? You have posted pretty much what you need, just use the database values (the `$red` array) instead of the flat variables you used in the question.

Comment: `$upit = "SELECT *,(((regular_price-sale_price)/sale_price)*100) as percentage FROM artikal INNER JOIN category ON id_category = category.id
                                    INNER JOIN store ON id_store = store.id
        " ;` Have you tried this way?

Comment: @danish-khan-I thank you its working, my formula is not correct so it should be like this : (((regular_price-sale_price)/regular_price)*100) .

Comment: @Johny is my answer helpful?

Comment: @KunalRaut  in my case, it was too complicated and I did not try it. But thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a php code to get the array of percentage values from the array of `$red['regular_price']` and `$red['sale_price']` so you need to set an empty array for the percentage values as

```
$red = ['regular_price' => [1,20,15,30],
        'sale_price'  => [32,50,64,98]
];
$precentage = [];
foreach ($red['regular_price'] as  $value) {
    foreach ($red['sale_price'] as $value1) {
        $precentage[] = (($value - $value1)/$value1) * 100;
    } 
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($precentage);
echo '</pre>';
```

And this code results in the following percentage array

[image]

**Note:** The values given here in the array are just for example therefore you are getting the result array as negative values but by using the same code you can get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I found the answer.

```
$upit = "SELECT *,(((regular_price-sale_price)/regular_price)*100) as percentage FROM artikal INNER JOIN category ON id_category = category.id INNER JOIN store ON id_store = store.id " ;
```